# How Can i Convert this multiple sub query in zend query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, zend-framework

i have the following query which gives desired output in mysql , now i want to implement it in zend query language,
which has different approach to implement the query..

```
SELECT A.NAME , B.PAYMENT , C.TOTALPROJ , D.TOTALTASK , T.ACTIVETASK , H.HOUR
FROM USERMASTER AS A 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
SELECT A.U_ID ,  SUM(A.TOTALTIME * B.RATE) AS PAYMENT
FROM 
(
SELECT U_ID , PROJECT_ID , 
SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(CASE WHEN endtime is null then timediff (starttime,starttime) 
ELSE timediff (endtime,starttime) END )) / 3600 AS TOTALTIME
FROM LOGMASTER AS A
WHERE PROJECT_ID IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY U_ID , PROJECT_ID
) AS A 
INNER JOIN PROJECTTOUSER AS B ON A.PROJECT_ID = B.PROJECT_ID AND A.U_ID = B.U_ID 
GROUP BY B.U_ID
) AS B ON A.ID = B.U_ID

LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
  SELECT U_ID , COUNT(*) AS TOTALPROJ FROM PROJECTTOUSER GROUP BY U_ID
) AS C ON A.ID = C.U_ID

LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
  SELECT ASSIGNED_TO , COUNT(*) AS TOTALTASK FROM TASKTOTARGET GROUP BY ASSIGNED_TO
) AS D ON A.ID = D.ASSIGNED_TO

LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
  SELECT ASSIGNED_TO,COUNT(*) AS ACTIVETASK FROM TASKTOTARGET WHERE 
IS_ACTIVE = 0    GROUP BY ASSIGNED_TO
) AS T ON A.ID = T.ASSIGNED_TO

LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
  SELECT U_ID, SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(CASE WHEN endtime is null then
 timediff (starttime,starttime) ELSE timediff (endtime,starttime) END ))) AS HOUR 
FROM LOGMASTER WHERE INSERT_DATE >= '2013-08-20' AND INSERT_DATE <='2013-08-31' 
GROUP BY U_ID
) AS H ON A.ID = H.U_ID
```

so if any one can guide me in how to create this query in zend then it will be very helpful, and appreciated

Comment: please do not use the query like this. It will slow down the process. Why do want to construct query? Better you can call this query using query method. $db->query($sql);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of your subqueries becomes an new Zend_Query that you can then use just like a table and pass in to the main query.

For example:

```
$h = new Zend_Db_Select()
    ->from('LOGMASTER', array('U_ID', 'HOUR' => new Zend_Db_Expr('SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(CASE WHEN endtime is null then
 timediff (starttime,starttime) ELSE timediff (endtime,starttime) END ))))')
    ->where("INSERT_DATE >= '2013-08-20'")
    ->where("INSERT_DATE <= '2013-08-31'")
    ->group('U_ID');

$mainQuery = new Zend_Db_Select()
      ->from('a' => 'USERMASTER', array('NAME'))
      ->joinLeft($h, 'A.ID = H.U_IS', array('HOUR'));
```

You would create each of your subqueries as its own object and then you can join them into your main query.  The last argument of the join function is which columns from the subquery should be added to the main query.

With ZF's fluid interface you can keep joining tables/queries until you have built your entire query.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.select.html

Comment: well, thanks for your feedback but zend_db_expr is giving me error in from clause, .  i have used sub  query in zend before with sililar approach without  zend_db_expr.. but for this instance i am not able to form the quite exact query,.. any ways thanks for the help, i'll keep trying..

Comment: it is taking 'u_id' and 'hour as table name i think , it says table 'U_ID' not found !! in db_expr line..